# Multiprocessing 2 different functions python3

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I am struggling for a while with `Multiprocessing` in `Python`. I would like to run 2 independent functions simultaneously, wait until both calculations are finished and then continue with the output of both functions. Something like this:

```
# Function A: 
def jobA(num):   
    result=num*2
    return result

# Fuction B:        
def jobB(num):
    result=num^3
    return result

 # Parallel process function: 

{resultA,resultB}=runInParallel(jobA(num),jobB(num))
```

I found other examples of multiprocessing however they used only one function or didn't returned an output. Anyone knows how to do this? Many thanks!

Comment: Are the functions I/O bound or processor bound?

Comment: have you tried `Pool.apply_async`?

Comment: Both functions are screenscraping data from a website so I guess it is I/O bound.

Comment: [Raymond Hettinger, Keynote on Concurrency, PyBay 2017](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9zinZmE3Ogk)

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend creating processes manually (rather than as part of a pool), and sending the return values to the main process through a `multiprocessing.Queue`. These queues can share almost any Python object in a safe and relatively efficient way.

Here's an example, using the jobs you've posted.

```
def jobA(num, q):
    q.put(num * 2)

def jobB(num, q):
    q.put(num ^ 3)

import multiprocessing as mp
q = mp.Queue()
jobs = (jobA, jobB)
args = ((10, q), (2, q))
for job, arg in zip(jobs, args):
    mp.Process(target=job, args=arg).start()

for i in range(len(jobs)):
    print('Result of job {} is: {}'.format(i, q.get()))
```

This prints out:

```
Result of job 0 is: 20
Result of job 1 is: 1
```

But you can of course do whatever further processing you'd like using these values.

Comment: Seems that the values/objects that each function puts in the queue should contain information about where it came from so that they can be used correctly - maybe like a tuple `(func_name, return_value)`.  `...wait until both calculations are finished...`:  you probably want  to `join` each process or a loop while either `is_alive` before executing the last for loop in your example.

Comment: @wwii Sure, you can add information about the "source" of any of the data, if you want. But there's no need to call `join()`, since the queue is thread/process-safe, and the call to `get()` will block until a new object is available.

Comment: @georgexsh No. `apply_async` calls a single function in one of the worker processes of a pool. The question asks how to call multiple *different* functions in parallel.

Comment: @bnaecker any difference with call `apply_async` multiple times and start enough processes in the pool? basically, you implemented a simplified version of Pool. besides, you don't need to pass `Queue` object as an argument to the worker function.

Comment: When all the processes finish and stop putting things in the queue will the `q.get` statement, in the last for loop, block indefinitely?

Comment: @wwii Yes, it will block. That's why I only loop for the number of tasks. It's also common to send sentinel values, which signal the end of processing. georgexsh's solution of `apply_async` for each task you need to run is also good, and avoids the queue entirely.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @ bneacker and the comments of you all! It works most of the time. Both functions actually represent an API connection to retrieve data from a website. These API's sometimes faile and then the parallel function just keeps on running forever. Any suggestions how to make it stop after an error when doing multiprocessing?

Comment: Check the return value from the API calls before placing them on the queue. If they succeed, place them. If they fail, then put some kind of "sentinel" value on the queue. `None` is a common choice for a sentinel.